# discord.js event handler welcome message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

so I made an event handler for my discord bot so that the index.js file would be neat. But for some reason the welcome message that I made whenever someone joins the server doesn't work.

Here's my event handler code:

```
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, Discord, client));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, Discord, client));
    }
}
```

And Here's my welcome message code:

```
module.exports =  {
    name: 'welcome',
    once: false,
    execute(Discord, client) {

    const welcomechannelId = '753484351882133507' //Channel You Want to Send The Welcome Message
    const targetChannelId = `846341557992292362` //Channel For Rules

        client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
            let welcomeRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Umay');
            member.roles.add(welcomeRole);

            const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomechannelId)

            const WelcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Welcome To ${member.guild.name}`)
            .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512}))
            .setDescription(`Hello <@${member.user.id}>, Welcome to **${member.guild.name}**. Thanks For Joining Our Server.
Please Read ${member.guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelId).toString()}, and assign yourself some roles at <#846341532520153088>. You can chat in <#753484351882133507> and talk with other people.`)
         // You Can Add More Fields If You Want
            .setFooter(`Welcome ${member.user.username}#${member.user.discriminator}`,member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512}))
            .setColor('RANDOM')
        member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomechannelId).send(WelcomeEmbed)
        
    })

    }
}
```

I get no error, but whenever someone joins the server, he/she won't be given the role and the welcome message doesn't appear. I put the welcome message code on an events folder that the event handler is handling. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do some debugging, log each variable in your event handler and confirm everything returns the expected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies within the welcome code.

In the handler code you have the following line:

```
client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, Discord, client));
```

This triggers the client on the name property set in the welcome code.

You currently have it set to `welcome`, which is not a valid event.
The bot is now listening for a welcome event, which will never happen.

First course of action is setting the name property to `guildMemberAdd` like this:

```
module.exports =  {
    name: 'guildMemberAdd',
//the rest of the code
```

Then you have another issue.
Within the welcome code you have `client.on()` *again*.

This will never work, unless by some incredibly lucky chance 2 people join within a millisecond of each other, but even then you'll only have 1 welcome message.

Removing the following:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
//code
})
```

will fix that issue.

Then the last thing to do is having the member value being imported correctly.
We do this by changing the following line:

```
execute(Discord, client) {
```

to:

```
execute(member, Discord, client) {
//code
```

The resulting code will look like this:

```
module.exports =  {
    name: 'guildMemberAdd',
    once: false,
    execute(member, Discord, client) {

    const welcomechannelId = '753484351882133507' //Channel You Want to Send The Welcome Message
    const targetChannelId = `846341557992292362` //Channel For Rules

            let welcomeRole = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Umay');
            member.roles.add(welcomeRole);

            const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomechannelId)

            const WelcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Welcome To ${member.guild.name}`)
            .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512}))
            .setDescription(`Hello <@${member.user.id}>, Welcome to **${member.guild.name}**. Thanks For Joining Our Server.
Please Read ${member.guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelId).toString()}, and assign yourself some roles at <#846341532520153088>. You can chat in <#753484351882133507> and talk with other people.`)
         // You Can Add More Fields If You Want
            .setFooter(`Welcome ${member.user.username}#${member.user.discriminator}`,member.user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 512}))
            .setColor('RANDOM')
        member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomechannelId).send(WelcomeEmbed)

    }
}
```

Happy coding!